# I want to remove elements from the list from the string when the elements of the list are in the string

Tags: python, list

Suppose

```
a = ['ab','bcd','efg','h']
b = ['wiab','wbcdz','rh','ksw','erer']
```

I want to remove any of the characters listed in `a` from list `b`.
result should be `['wi','wz','r','ksh','erer']

This is the code I tried :

```
result = []
for i in b:
    if not any(word in i for word in a):
        result.append(word)
```

But this code returns
`result = ['ksw','erer']`

please help me

Comment: I don't really understand your expected output, what happens to `'ksw'` and `'erer'` in list b?

Comment: sorry  result = ['ksw','erer'] It's just the result I've tried.

Comment: The result I want to see is result should be ['wi', wz, 'r']

Comment: Yes, that is clear. Why? What happens to those final two entries? Why do they get removed from b?

Comment: So actually what you are saying is that you want to return only the string that contain strings from the first list but the part without it.

Comment: In fact, this is a problem that originally came from dealing with stopwords in non-English languages. a is stopword and b is tokenize word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions give you what you want so here is one for a bit of fun. You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with a custom function.

```
from functools import reduce

a = ['ab','bcd','efg','h']
b = ['wiab','wbcdz','rh','ksw','erer']


def remove(x, y):
    return x.replace(y, '')

out = [reduce(remove, a, i) for i in b]
```

giving

```
['wi', 'wz', 'r', 'ksw', 'erer']
```

*Edit:* 
Probably the least clear way you could write this would be as a one-liner with a lambda :)

```
[reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, ''), a, i) for i in b]
```

Comment: thank you so much . This works really well. Excuse me, but can I ask what kind of custom fuction is?

Comment: Well I just define the `remove` function that calls `str.replace`. The key part is the use of `reduce`. You could also use a lambda here but I find defining a function clearer e.g. `[reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, ''), a, i) for i in b]`

Comment: @tomjn you should add the lambda version as part of your solution as well. That's what I was thinking as well, but it seems you got that covered as well :)

Answer (score 3):

```
def function(a,b):
    result = []
    for i in a:
        for word in b:
            if i in word:
                result.append(word.replace(i,''))
    return result
```

The `any` function in your code is unnecessary. You need to loop through both lists, then check if your substring is in the string of the other list, call the `replace` method on your word containing the substring, and then add it to your list of results

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = ['ab','bcd','efg','h']
b = ['wiab','wbcdz','rh','ksw','erer']

result = []
for i in b:
    for word in a:
        if word in i:
            result.append(i.replace(word, ''))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['wi', 'wz', 'r']
```